# Modify custom Users Manage page

Tags: customization, users, user-roles, admin-menu, request-filter

I'm trying to create a **submenu page** under '**Users**' which is like the 'All Users' page but **for listing users of specific roles only**. Let's just call this submenu page **'Customer'**.

So far I managed to create one with its own columns, but there are still some things that I haven't managed to modify **to make the contents more relevant**:

> [image: Custom User Page]

### Here's what I need to do:

1. How do I **change the page title** to reflect the submenu name, in this case 'Customer'?
2. (a) How do I change the **filter links above the list to show ONLY 'All', 'Subscriber', & 'Pending'**? (b) And also the **'Change role to..' dropdown menu**?
3. How do I change the filter link **'All' to direct to the 'Customer' page** (which is the custom users page)?
4. How do I make the **'Customer' submenu link to hilite** to indicate the current page viewed?

> **NOTE:**
>   The default '**All Users**' page should therefore be **the
>   opposite** of this page in terms of the **filter links**.

### Here's roughly how I created the above page:

```
/* Create new user submenu with custom parameter in slug */
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_custom_user_submenu');
function my_custom_user_submenu() {
    add_users_page(
        'Customer',
        'Customer',
        list_users,
        'users.php?user=custom'
    );
}

/* Filter users according to the users list page */
add_action('pre_user_query','my_user_customer_list');
function my_user_customer_list($user_search) {

    $user = $_GET['custom'];
    $role = $_GET['role'];

    if ( $user == 'custom' OR $role == 'subscriber' OR $role == 'pending' ) {

        global $wpdb;

        /* For Customers Page:
         * Get only 'Subscriber' & 'Pending' users
         * */
        $user_search->query_where = 
        str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
                "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
                    SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
                        WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}user_level' 
                        AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value = 0)", 
                $user_search->query_where
        );

    } else {

        global $wpdb;

        /* For User Admin Page:
         * Get all apart from 'Subscriber' & 'Pending' users
         * */
        $user_search->query_where = 
        str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
                "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
                    SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
                        WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}user_level' 
                        AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value >= 1)", 
                $user_search->query_where
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I managed to modify the page. For the **submenu highlighting**, however, I haven't managed to figure it out, so I **resort to jQuery**.

### Here's the code:

```
/* - Set user filter links according to users pages
 * - Set Role Change dropdown menu
 * */
function custom_user_filter_links( $views ) {

  global $wp_roles; // For Role Change dropdown menu

  $amt       = count_users();
  $amtCustom = $amt['avail_roles']['subscriber'] + $amt['avail_roles']['pending']; // Count custom users

  if ( $_GET['user'] == 'custom' || $_GET['role'] == 'subscriber' || $_GET['role'] == 'pending' ) {

    /* For Customers Page: */

    /* Modify url & users count for the 'All' link */
    $all = preg_replace( '/(.*\.php)(.*\().*(\).*)/', '$1?user=custom${2}'.$amtCustom.'$3', $views['all'] );

    /* Show only 'Subscriber' & 'Pending' user links */
    $arr = array();
      $arr['all']          = $all;
      if ($views['subscriber'])
        $arr['subscriber'] = $views['subscriber'];
      if ($views['pending'])
        $arr['pending']    = $views['pending'];
    $views = $arr;

    /* Modify Role Change dropdown menu */
    $arr = array();
      $arr['subscriber'] = $wp_roles->roles['subscriber'];
      $arr['pending']    = $wp_roles->roles['pending'];
    $wp_roles->roles = $arr;

  } else {

    /* For User Admin Page: */

    /* Modify users count for the 'All' link*/
    $views['all'] = preg_replace( '/(.*\().*(\).*)/', '${1}'.($amt['total_users'] - $amtCustom).'$2', $views['all'] );

    /* Remove 'Subscriber' & 'Pending' user links  */
    unset($views['subscriber']);
    unset($views['pending']);

    /* Modify Role Change dropdown menu */
    unset ( $wp_roles->roles['subscriber'] );
    unset ( $wp_roles->roles['pending'] );

  }

  return $views;
}
add_filter( 'views_users', 'custom_user_filter_links' );


/* - Highlight custom submenu
 * - Change titles of custom Users Manage & Edit pages
 * */
function submenu_hilite_n_rename_title() {

  global $current_screen;

  // If not in specified pages than discontinue
  if( !($current_screen->base == 'users' || $current_screen->base == 'user-edit') )
      return;

  global $title;

  if ($current_screen->base == 'user-edit') {
    /* For Edit User page */
    $user  = get_user_by('id', $_GET['user_id']);
    $role  = $user->roles[0];
    $title = 'Edit Customer'; /* Change page title */
  } else {
    /* For Manage Users page */
    $role  = $_GET['role'];
    $title = 'Customers'; /* Change page title */
  }

  switch (true) {
    case $_GET['user'] == 'custom'      :
    case $role         == 'subscriber'  :
    case $role         == 'pending'     :
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
          var reference = $('a[href$="user=custom"]').parent();

          // Highlight custom submenu
          reference.addClass('current');

          // Remove highlight from default menu
          reference.parent().find('li:first').removeClass('current');             
        });     
      </script>
      <?php
      break;
  }

}
add_action('admin_head', submenu_hilite_n_rename_title);
```